# Options for a server container framework for Ruby/JRuby

Tags: ruby, frameworks, jruby

Looking to do a Ruby-based server component and wondering what wrapper to give it, if any?

It will be JRuby, so Spring comes to mind - but perhaps there are more Ruby-centric options?

Thanks in advance, Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most "rubyish" thing would be to use mongrel or webrick, but I don't think very many folks do that.

I think the most common thing is to use Rails or Sinatra, then package them using as a war file using [warbler](http://kenai.com/projects/warbler/pages/Home).  At that point, anything that can host a war file can host the app.

There's a pretty good list [here](http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/JRubyOnRails).

Comment: Thanks - wasnt planning on running a web front end, just a server - an interface, grabs some data, reformats it and then passes it to another system.